# Define Launcher Activity In Code Before Activities Loaded

Tags: android

I realise you can set the LAUNCHER activity of your app in the manifest file, but is there anyway you can statically do this in code before the activity is loaded by the Dalvik VM? Something like:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity{

      RunTime.LAUNCHER = MyActivity.class
      ...

}
```

I realise this might not be possible, but if it is I would appreciate a safe and reliable code example to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: this is not possible. it is made at compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is possible, however, is to have a first empty activity that starts whatever activity you need next, without displaying itself.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle stuff) {
    super.onCreate(stuff);
    startActivity(new Intent(...whatever...);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: This is what I would suggest as well. I have used this previously, and it works fine.

Comment: Ahh so from what you are saying could I set my LAUNCHER activity as some HelperActivity, that could have a static field that could be set by other classes. It would then read the value of this static field in onCreate and launch the configured activity... thereby simulating the ability to update the LAUNCHER activity in code? Thanks for your help

Comment: probably not a static field, no, as it could not be modified before being read in this case. may be rather a sharedpreference

Comment: SharedPreference is a very interesting suggestion! Did not consider that, thank you!